# Passing a value stored in IBAction to the next Nib UITextField.

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uibutton, uitextfield

I am trying to build a calculator consists of a set of values are constant and some values are variables.

The calculator will first be initiated from a UIButton and i want to store the constant values number in the UIButton using IBAction. Then by touching the button will initiate the calculator with the constant value display on the UITextField.

My question is, what code can i type in to store the constant values within the code of IBAction and display it on the next nib file UITextField. Below is my current code.

Many Thanks.

```
 - (IBAction)runningtrack:(id)sender {

int length = 400;
int width = 30;

 track *myView3 =[[track alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [myView3 setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
        [self presentModalViewController:myView3 animated:YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can use delegate methos or easily(not preferred) us NSUSerDefaults. If yu use NSUserDefaults, your code will be something like this.

```
- (IBAction)runningtrack:(id)sender {

int length = 400;
int width = 30;
NSNumber *theNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:<lenght&with or which int value you will save>];//NSUSerDefaults saves property list objects, so convert int to NSNumber
NSUserDefaults *savedValue=[NSUserDefaults standartuserdefault];
[savedValue setObject:theNumber forKey:@"myConst"];
 track *myView3 =[[track alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];// by the way i don't think initWithNibName:nil give a proper response, it must crash
        [myView3 setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
        [self presentModalViewController:myView3 animated:YES];
    }
```

In the other class(which has the .xib you want to display tat value)

```
  NSNumber *yourValue=[[NSUserDefaults standartuserdefault] objectForKey:@"myConst"];
UITextView *yourTextView=...
yourTextView.text=yourValue;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare property in `track` class or make custom init method.

1. Property

   ```
   track *myView3 =[[track alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
   track.valueForTextField = width; //valueForTextField is a int property in track class
   ```
2. Custom init:

   ```
   track *myView3 =[[track alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil andMyValue:width];
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the following custom init method.

`track *myView3 =[[track alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil customLength:400       customWidth:300];`

You must follow the below steps before using the above code.

1. In the track.h header file, add custom init method declaration.

   `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle customLength:(int) customWidth:(int);`
2. In the track.m file, add the custom method definition.

   `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle customLength:(int) customWidth:(int) { 
   /*You can use the customLength and customWidth here  */}`